# How do I use require.js on the serverside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I use it on the client right now with Backbone.js, but I'd like to use it with node.js also.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are directions on the requirejs homepage that I found pretty useful: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

I also set up some examples here: https://github.com/rgarcia/node-requirejs-examples

The basic idea is that you use it just like on the client side, but for npm modules and built-in node modules, you don't use the relative path, but rather the module name. For all of your custom modules you use the relative path.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the doc for usage of requireJS on node.js

http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Install the node.js

```
npm install requirejs
```

Usage example

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs(['foo', 'bar'],
function   (foo,   bar) {
    //foo and bar are loaded according to requirejs
    //config, but if not found, then node's require
    //is used to load the module.
});
```

Comment: This answer contains something that I think Node newbies like myself didn't realize: You have have to require requirejs itself as a separate object! Very helpful.